# Passing session variable from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I've done this with PHP a while back, and now I want to do it with C#. I think I might be on the right track but something is going wrong along the way.

What I have is a "Create Order" page, which contains a basket of items that a user would like to purchase. On this page, they can search for products by name or sku, and grid view of results is displayed if they typed in something valid. They can then navigate to an add/update page where they can either add a new product to the basket or edit/update one already there. This takes them back to the basket page.

On the "Create Order" page, I am setting a session variable with the Cart ID based on whether a cart id is found in the url query string:

```
    protected void CreateSessionVariable()
    {
        string session = "";
        if (Request.QueryString["CartID"] != "" & Request.QueryString["CartID"] != null)
        {
            session = Request.QueryString["CartID"];
            Session["CartValue"] = session;
        }
        else
            Session["CartValue"] = "";
    }
```

I am then calling this is the Page_Load function:

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindBasketGrid();
            //call function
            if (Session["CartValue"] != "" & Session["CartValue"] != null)
            {
                string CartCode = Request.QueryString["CartID"];
                CartIDLbl.Visible = true;
                CartIDLbl.Text += CartCode;
            }
            else
                CreateSessionVariable();
        }
```

In the add/update page's Page_Load, this is what I am calling (and it is called within !Page.IsPostBack:

```
                if (Session["CartValue"] != "" & Session["CartValue"] != null)
                {
                    string CartCode = Session["CartValue"].ToString();
                    CartIDLbl.Visible = true;
                    CartIDLbl.Text += CartCode;
                }
```

Things work for a little while--the Session variable is passed from the "Create Order" page to the Add/Update page successfully. But, when returning to the Create Order page, the session variable is no longer set.

Am I setting things up incorrectly?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace for your `Else` statement in your first code block on top of Patrick's answer, and a closing brace for your `Else` block in your second code block.

Answer (score 0):

The [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.120).aspx) you are using makes the condition `Session["CartValue"] != "" & Session["CartValue"] != null` an bitwise AND.

In C#, you need `&&` to do an AND:

```
if (Session["CartValue"] != "" && Session["CartValue"] != null
```

This statement can be written easier like this:

```
string s = Session["CartValue"] as string;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

Comment: Ok, I have made this change but the session variable is still not being passed between the two pages successfully...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if the Session variable *CartValue* is well-written in the "Create Order" page and if the conditions for generate the session variable is happening?

I suggest you check the value of session variable outside of !IsPostback condition:

```
    //Create a private variable.
    private string CartValue;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check your session variable "will be empty if the session variable is null".
        CartValue = Session["CartValue"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CartValue"].ToString()) ? Session["CartValue"].ToString() : "";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Your code...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking Session Variable like-

```
Session["CartValue"] != "" & Session["CartValue"] != null
```

Is wrong.

Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'. You should check if Session variable is NULL or NOT. If not NULL then if Session Variable's value is null or empty.

```
if (Session["CartValue"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CartValue"].ToString())){
    // your code..
}
```